# Segmentation fault in C, can't figure why

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a function that is supposed to read (in a very bad way) a file. I expect it to modify a struct that I pass as a parameter to store the things that it has to read. But when I call it, it throws a segmentation fault. I have a print as the first thing the function does, and it doesn't do it. So I guess I have a problem with the declaration of the function or something. I can't figure it out.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    //some parser here
    struct client_config *config;
    read_software_config_file(*config); //I also passed it as non pointer and & but nothing worked.
    } 

void read_software_config_file(struct client_config config){
    printf("Hello"); //it breaks here
  }
```

As someone pointed out I did this:

```
 struct client_config config;
 read_software_config_file(&config);
```

But it still shows me segmentation fault.

Comment: `config` is not pointing anywhere, but you dereference it when calling the function. *Undefined behavior* as it is.

Comment: so how can I solve it?

Comment: Define `config` as a structure, not pointer to it. Then pass it's address.

Comment: I just did and it still get the segmentation fault

Comment: Then you have some other issues, or you didn't do it properly. Post a proper [mcve].

Comment: Your `read_software_config_file` should take pointer, by the way. Do you see the compiler warnings? You should have some.

Comment: I have 0 compilers warnings, now I changed it and it is declared that it receives a pointer. But it still doesn't work

Comment: @raultds what is your compiler ? what options you use to compile ? What is the new code still not working ? What is `client_config` definition ?

Comment: @raultds if you do `read_software_config_file(&config);` the argument is a `struct client_config *` but `void read_software_config_file(struct client_config config)`. Do you understand what is a pointer is ? Again what is your compiler to ask for more warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct client_config
{
    int data;
};

void read_software_config_file(struct client_config *config); // Forward Declaration

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct client_config config; // Memory on stack. Use malloc/calloc for heap
    config.data = 10; // Init data
    read_software_config_file(&config);
    printf("config.data = %d\n", config.data);

    return 0;
}

void read_software_config_file(struct client_config *config)
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    config->data = 12;
}
```

I would generally advise to compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to catch errors early.

You have to forward declare the function `read_software_config_file` (or include a header etc.) s.t. the compiler knows the signature when you call it in main.

As said in the comments you should take a pointer to the struct, s.t. it can be modified.

The output after running main is:

```
Hello
config.data = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare any variable, pointer or not, without initializing it, it gets whatever is in memory as its current value. Some higher level languages may implicitly initialize all new values with "default" variables. You may have gotten used to this from previous programming experience; this is not the case in C.

If you use the `*` dereference operator on an uninitialized pointer, you are dereferencing whatever address is represented by the current value of the pointer, which is undefined behavior, and almost certainly going to cause an access violation.

You need to initialize your pointer to point to something; either an existing `struct client_config`, or new heap memory allocated with `malloc` or `calloc`.

Also, if your function really is meant to take a pointer to a `struct client_config`, the parameter should have a `*` operator on it as well.